# Multi-dimension spatial query in couchdb

Tags: couchdb, geospatial

Using CouchDB (and GeoCouch), I have a document type of Location with a center coordinate (lat & long) that I am able to query with a bbox query just fine by feeding in a northwest longitude/latitude and a southwest longitude/latitued. My location doc also has an attribute called Users where I have a list of users. I would like to be able to perform a bbox with the addition of filtering by a specific user in the Users array. Is this possible?

Added details on the problem:
The reason important is because I may have a million different location documents, each with a list of users in the User array (maybe 10-100 user tags per location).  I'm trying to find a list of locations for a group of users.  So I have 3 users for a particular search and I want to find all of the locations for these users within a given boundry.  The only way I can think to handle this scenario is to perform the bbox spatial query first and then loop through the result set to determine if the user matches the list of the 3 users.  This would mean looping through a potentially very large original result set (the list of locations).  Seems very inefficient. Would love to add an additional dimension to my bbox query to filter also by user, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this or whether it is possible.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding an additional parameter is not possible (from what I could gather).  You can do the bbox, then with the results perform and additional search on the additional parm, but that would have been a lot of extra network traffic between the application and the database.

I ended up switching from iriscouch to cloudant.  The lucene search indexing feature gave me what I needed.  You can index the lat/lon and then add an additional parm...awesome!

Iriscouch may have this feature, but I couldn't find it.

geo?q=lat:[90 TO 0] AND lon:[150 TO 0] AND user:username